# Drupal 8: convert node id from string to integer

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Retrieve a node based on condition:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
->condition('title', 'my node title');
$nid = $query->execute();
```

The result of $nid is the correct node ID but the format is a string, (es: "123")

When I want to load the node by its ID, I write:

```
$node_id = Node::load($nid);
```

Doing this, the result I get is NULL because the variable $nid is holding a string (not integer).
If I write the code like this:

```
$node_id = Node::load(123);
```

I get the node loaded.

How can I convert the variable string ($nid) as an integer ?
I tried:

```
$nid_int = (int) $nid;
$node_id = Node::load($nid_int);
```

also I tried:

```
$nid_int = intval($nid);
$node_id = Node::load($nid_int);
```

But I alwas get result NULL

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use **Node::load($nid);** directly, because the **$query->execute()** return an array like **['vid' => "nid"]**.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
->condition('title', 'my node title');
$nids = $query->execute();
$nid = (int)array_shift($nids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try:-

```
$nid_string = $nid->__toString();
$node_id = Node::load((int) $nid_string);
```

Comment: I got the following error message from your code suggestion:
`Error: Call to a member function __toString() on array`

Comment: It seems $nid is an array. You can check using var_dump($nid). In that case no need to use _toString() just take value from array.